# ARIMA estimation by hand

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, optimization, box-jenkins

I'm trying to understand how the parameters are estimated in ARIMA modeling/Box Jenkins (BJ). Unfortunately none of the books that I have encountered describes the estimation procedure such as Log-Likelihood estimation procedure in detail.  Following is the Log-Likelihood for ARMA from any standard textbooks:
$$
LL(\theta)=-\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi) - \frac{n}{2}\log(\sigma^2) - \sum\limits_{t=1}^n\frac{e_t^2}{2\sigma^2}
$$

I want to learn the ARIMA/BJ estimation by doing it myself. So I used $R$ to write a code for estimating ARMA by hand. Below is what I did in $R$,

- I simulated ARMA (1,1)
- Wrote the above equation as a function
- Used the simulated data and the optim function to estimate AR and MA parameters.
- I also ran the ARIMA in the stats package and compared the ARMA
  parameters from what I did by hand.
  ***Below is the comparison:***

[image: Comparison]

**Below are my questions:

- **Why is there a slight difference between the estimated and calculated
  variables ?**
- **Does ARIMA function in R backcasts or does the estimation procedure    differently than what is outlined below in my code?**
- **I have assigned e1 or error at observation 1 as 0, is this correct ?**
- **Also is there a way to estimate confidence bounds of forecasts using the hessian
  of the optimization ?**

Thanks so much for your help as always.

Below is the code:

```
## Load Packages

library(stats)
library(forecast)

set.seed(456)


## Simulate Arima
y <- arima.sim(n = 250, list(ar = 0.3, ma = 0.7), mean = 5)
plot(y)

## Optimize Log-Likelihood for ARIMA

n = length(y) ## Count the number of observations
e = rep(1, n) ## Initialize e

logl <- function(mx){
  
  g <- numeric
  mx <- matrix(mx, ncol = 4)
  
  mu <- mx[,1] ## Constant Term
  sigma <- mx[,2] 
  rho <- mx[,3] ## AR coeff
  theta <- mx[,4] ## MA coeff
  
  e[1] = 0 ## Since e1 = 0
  
  for (t in (2 : n)){
    e[t] = y[t] - mu - rho*y[t-1] - theta*e[t-1]
  }
  
  ## Maximize Log-Likelihood Function 
  g1 <-  (-((n)/2)*log(2*pi) - ((n)/2)*log(sigma^2+0.000000001) - (1/2)*(1/(sigma^2+0.000000001))*e%*%e)
  
  ##note: multiplying Log-Likelihood by "-1" in order to maximize in the optimization
  ## This is done becuase Optim function in R can only minimize, "X"ing by -1 we can maximize
  ## also "+"ing by 0.000000001 sigma^2 to avoid divisible by 0
  g <- -1 * g1
  
  return(g)
  
}

## Optimize Log-Likelihood
arimopt <- optim(par=c(10,0.6,0.3,0.5), fn=logl, gr = NULL,
                 method = c("L-BFGS-B"),control = list(), hessian = T)
arimopt

############# Output Results###############
ar1_calculated = arimopt$par[3]
ma1_calculated = arimopt$par[4]
sigmasq_calculated = (arimopt$par[2])^2
logl_calculated = arimopt$val
ar1_calculated
ma1_calculated
sigmasq_calculated
logl_calculated

############# Estimate Using Arima###############
est <- arima(y,order=c(1,0,1))
est
```

Comment: What is the relationship between $T$ and $n$?  Your code has no "$T$" in it.  Perhaps $T=n+1$?  If so, there would be an obvious bug in the calculation of `g1`.  You need to dispense with the `+0.000000001` stuff, too, even though that changes the answer only a little: for small $\sigma$ it will ensure you report incorrect values of this parameter.

Comment: I have changed the equation and now reflects what is in the code. I'm not sure how I could remove +0.000000001 becuase it will cause "NaNs" due to divisible by 0 and also due to the issue of log (0)

Comment: If you keep the additive offsets to `sigma^2`, you will need to solve for `sigma` after running the optimization (by subtracting the offset from the fitted value and taking the square root of the result).

Comment: There is the concept of exact likelihood. It requires the knowledge of initial parameters such as the fist value of the MA error (one of your questions). Implementations usually differ regarding how they treat the initial values. What I usually do is (which is not mentioned in many books) is to also maximize ML w.r.t. the initial values as well.

Comment: @whuber even if I replace 0.000000001 with 1e-100 I'm still getiing the same results.  Thanks for your response and recommendations.

Comment: `1e-100` when added to the values of `sigma^2` which typically would be passed as arguments to your function will be the same as adding $0$ (you only have 16 sig figs or so, not 100), so you have shown you don't need the additive offset. I was cautious in my earlier remark: I did not assert that *these* results would be affected, but that they would when $\sigma$ is sufficiently small.

Comment: @whuber, thanks again. While I was experimenting with the code, I notice for one randome simulation, I got NaN and error becuse the optimizer was searching for 0. I'll remove 0.0000001 as it no longer needed for this seed.

Comment: Please take a look at the following from Tsay, it is not covering all cases, but was quite helpful for me: http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/uts/lec8-08.pdf

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc as pointed by you initial values is the cause of difference. I can accept your comment as answer if you post your comments as an answer.

Comment: @forecaster, your link is not working. Could you please post a full reference and a new link?

Comment: @RichardHardy since its a standard log likelihood from any standard time series textbook, the link is not necessary.

Comment: @forecaster, thanks! I was curious to see if there were some other relevant things in that reference, so that is why I asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the concept of exact likelihood. It requires the knowledge of initial parameters such as the fist value of the MA error (one of your questions). Implementations usually differ regarding how they treat the initial values. What I usually do is (which is not mentioned in many books) is to also maximize ML w.r.t. the initial values as well.

Please take a look at the following from Tsay, it is not covering all cases, but was quite helpful for me:

http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/uts/lec8-08.pdf

Comment: The link does not work.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I don't know how to remedy the situation. The author removed it.

Answer (score 5):

Did you read the the help page of `arima` function? Here is the relevant excerpt:

> The exact likelihood is computed via a state-space representation of
>   the ARIMA process, and the innovations and their variance found by a
>   Kalman filter. The initialization of the differenced ARMA process uses
>   stationarity and is based on Gardner et al. (1980). For a differenced
>   process the non-stationary components are given a diffuse prior
>   (controlled by kappa). Observations which are still controlled by the
>   diffuse prior (determined by having a Kalman gain of at least 1e4) are
>   excluded from the likelihood calculations. (This gives comparable
>   results to arima0 in the absence of missing values, when the
>   observations excluded are precisely those dropped by the
>   differencing.)

Also relevant is a parameter `method=c("CSS-ML", "ML", "CSS")`:

> Fitting method: maximum likelihood or minimize conditional
>   sum-of-squares. The default (unless there are missing values) is to
>   use conditional-sum-of-squares to find starting values, then maximum
>   likelihood.

Your results do not differ that much from the ones produced by `arima` function, so you definitely got everything right.

Remember that if you want to compare results of two optimisation procedures, you need to make sure, that the starting values are the same, and the same optimisation method is used, otherwise the results might differ.