# ARMA coefficients

Tags: estimation, arma

How to determine the ARMA coefficients for ARMA(p,q)?

I explored a lot of technical literature and I understand there are standard rules like Yule-Walker for a pure AR process.

Do they apply for ARMA processes too? If yes, then I know how to apply it and solve part of the problem.

How to determine the MA coefficients of ARMA: are there generic equations?

Comment: Take a look at Hamilton "Time Series Analysis". He discusses estimating AR, MA and ARMA models using maximum likelihood estimation in Chapter 5. Sections 5.4-5.7 should be particularly useful.

Comment: See also this thread: ["ARIMA estimation by hand"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77663/arima-estimation-by-hand).